# Replace text with HTML tag in LXML text element

Tags: python, lxml

I have some `lxml` element:

```
>> lxml_element.text
  'hello BREAK world'
```

I need to replace the word `BREAK` with an HTML break tag—`<br />`. I've tried to do simple text replacing:

```
lxml_element.text.replace('BREAK', '<br />')
```

but it inserts the tag with escaped symbols, like `&lt;br/&gt;`. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you could do it. Setting up a sample lxml from your question:

```
>>> import lxml
>>> some_data = "<b>hello BREAK world</b>"
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(some_data)
>>> root
<Element b at 0x3f35a50>
>>> root.text
'hello BREAK world'
```

Next, create a subelement tag <br>:

```
>>> childbr = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, "br")
>>> childbr
<Element br at 0x3f35b40>
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(root)
'<b>hello BREAK world<br/></b>'
```

But that's not all you want. You have to take the text before the <br> and place it in `.text`:

```
>>> root.text = "hello"
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(root)
'<b>hello<br/></b>'
```

Then set the `.tail` of the child to contain the rest of the text:

```
>>> childbr.tail = "world"
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(root)
'<b>hello<br/>world</b>'
```

Comment: Well, I got the same problem and this solution works, but it's a pain to use. Is there no simpler solution or out-of-the-box function for that?

Comment: one problem here is if tail contains additional tags. They are wrotten with escaped html entities like &lt

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't think you want to just change the text node of the element. What I think you want to do is to modify the `text` node of your `Element` add a `SubElement` of name `br` to your `lxml_element` and then set the `tail` attribute of your subelement to the 2nd part of the string you are parsing. I found the tutorial here: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class to be very useful.